# How can I send file from postman to node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload

I want to upload file from postman to node js but I have problem. 
POSTMAN
Write url,check post method,check form-data,check file,write file name and choose file
This is my code
app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

app.use(fileUpload());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

router.js

```
router.post('/schedule/entry', function(req,res){
   console.log(req.file.name);
});
```

Console return me undefined name, if I write this code

```
router.post('/schedule/entry', function(req,res){
   console.log(req.file);
});
```

Return 'undefined'
Why?

package.json

```
  {
   "name": "nodejs-rest-api-authentication",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "app.js",
   "scripts": {
   "start": "node server.js",
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 },
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
  "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
  "body-parser": "^1.16.1",
  "csv-array": "0.0.22",
  "csv-write-stream": "^2.0.0",
  "express": "^4.14.1",
  "express-fileupload": "^0.3.0",
"fast-csv": "^2.4.1",
"formidable": "^1.1.1",
"json2csv": "^3.11.5",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.0",
"mysql": "^2.15.0"
  }
 }
```

server.js

```
const app = require('./app');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = app.listen(port, function() {
console.log('Server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

[screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsxds.png)
[screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS1Ox.png)

[codeGit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp0mh.png)

Comment: What's inside `req`?

Comment: you haven't shown what you're doing in `postman` ... so, do we guess?

Comment: What is your interest?

Comment: @A.Vahagn if you don't show how this is called, we can only guess at what's wrong.

Comment: oh .. so, you don't want help, you're probably doing it wrong herp

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP doesn't want help after all

Comment: @JaromandaX, there's the "Questions seeking debugging help..." reason for closing, you're just being needlessly snarky.

Comment: What I write wrong? Tell me and I ask question to details

Comment: @A.Vahagn show the actual request, for starters. Or at least the content of `req` inside the router.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion in the comment section:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const formidable = require('formidable')
const path = require('path')
const uploadDir = '' // uploading the file to the same path as app.js

app.post('/', (req, res) =>{
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
  form.multiples = true
  form.keepExtensions = true
  form.uploadDir = uploadDir
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json({ error: err })
    res.status(200).json({ uploaded: true })
  })
  form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file) {
    const [fileName, fileExt] = file.name.split('.')
    file.path = path.join(uploadDir, `${fileName}_${new Date().getTime()}.${fileExt}`)
  })
});


app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

Attached Screenshots[image]:
[image]

[image]

Comment: When I send request to postman, POSTMAN loading and code form.parse not logged in.
I dont now. Where is my problem?

Comment: Can you share your packages.json of the code base and I can try replicating the same at my end?

Comment: also your app.js  & server.js please

Comment: Updated the answer, I have just tested it using POSTMAN

Comment: Code not working, When I write console.log() in form.parse parth or form.on parth not working. I dont now why?

Comment: show me how are you trying the console.log() statement. The code I posted is working 100%

Comment: It's working just fine. See the third screenshot I just uploaded. Are you sure your server.js is working fine?

Comment: Just download the code form the URL: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dtqdmjkoqyjy6az/test.zip?dl=0 and run "npm start" from the terminal

Comment: Yes I am sure, server.js working. I think another problem,but I dont now where is problem. I tried to use express-fileupload module but not working.
I only need to get the file name, .CSV file name

Comment: you can adapt the code from the above URL and change it as per your need.

Comment: Your code working, but my problem is not solved
This is my current project github
https://github.com/aleksanyanV/appointment_app/
and this is my problem path
https://github.com/aleksanyanV/appointment_app/blob/master/controllers/schedule/entry.js
addCsv method

Comment: So that means there is certainly something wrong in your setup of the codebase. At least my code gives you a direction to look into.

Comment: If it is not difficult for you, please help me find the solution in my code.

Comment: I already add screenshot this file
https://github.com/aleksanyanV/appointment_app/blob/master/controllers/schedule/entry.js

Comment: At first this code worked, Then I did not understand what happened

Answer (score 0):

Because of body-parser middleware file will be not available in req so you must use another middleware libraries like [`connect-busboy`](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy) or [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) or [`connect-multiparty`](https://github.com/andrewrk/connect-multiparty)